# Can you create a distinct Hibernate in-memory database for each thread (for testing)?

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, kotlin

I've been implementing Hibernate and JPA interfaces for testing backed by a map of maps.  This data structure makes a really simple "database":

```
// All my database classes implement this (Kotlin) interface.
// "Idd" means "having an ID" as in "ID'd"
interface Idd {
    val id: Long
}

// This simple data structure works as an in-memory database.
//
// The Class is the name of the mapped entity class (which extends Idd)
//
// The inner map uses the ID as the key and the actual objects as
// the value.
//
// ID's are assigned by looking up the Class in the outer map
// and adding one to the size of the inner map (in a synchronized block).
map: SortedMap<Class<Idd>,
               MutableMap<Long, Idd>>
```

I wrap Hibernate's EntityManager so that a test can pass it a new map instead of connecting to a real database.  I pass it a separate map for each test and have the test set up whatever data it needs so that tests running simultaneously in different threads are completely separate from each other.

This works great (it was kind of a breakthrough for my testing), but the relevant Hibernate/JPA classes have a lot of methods and change quite a bit between versions of Hibernate.

I've heard that Hibernate ships with an in-memory database.  Can this be used with a separate database per thread for testing?  An example would be great!

P.S. I use a Sorted/Tree-Map because I can print it out in a reliable order for debugging.

Comment: If you need an in-memory database then it's not a unit test. A unit test would use a mock. If you need an in-memory database then it's closer to an integration test.

Comment: @Michael I removed the word "unit" from my question.  Yes, code with database is technically integration.  But it's darn useful and quick so I run these with my unit tests.

Comment: @GlenPeterson heh I've just started facing the same problem. have you found a solution for that problem?

Comment: @user007 I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an H2 In-memory Database**

I tried the map-of-maps idea in my question for testing, but I was seduced into implementing more and more Hibernate interfaces which changed with each new Hibernate release.  Also, it got really complicated.  Eventually I ripped all that out and used the H2 in-memory database instead.

You need to add the dependency to your build (test-scope only):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Consider Using the same DB for all tests**

My project, on my machine, takes about 2 seconds to create the H2 database, get Hibernate rolling, and spin the whole thing up before the first test.  You don't want to add that wait to every test if you can help it!  Much better to only initialize the H2 database once and *use a distinct root node for every test so that nothing can intersect in the database.*

Everything in my database is segregated by Company which has a unique `name` field.  Users have a company, etc.  So at the beginning of each test, I say, `co = newCo("nameUniqueToThisTest")` and then `new User(co, ...)` etc.  That way the data from 2 tests won't ever overwrite.  And if it ever does, then your data siloing isn't working very well, which is a bigger problem and good to discover!

Here is the newCo() method that ensures uniqueness:

```
private val coNames: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

@JvmStatic
fun newCo(nm: String): Company {
    synchronized(coNames) {
        val lcName: String = nm.toLowerCase()
        if (coNames.contains(lcName)) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't have two companies with the same name (case insensitive): $nm")
        }
        coNames.add(lcName)
    }
    val co = Company(nm)
    save(co) // assigns ID
    return co
}
```

If your database is not separated, you may need to create a new database for each test.  If so, you won't need lazy initialization, because you'll use a different init for every test.  In that case, make sure to vary the `myDb` database name for each test so they don't overwrite each other's data in a different order every time they run.

**My Lazily-initialized Solution**

My solution uses a lazily-initialized, thread-safe variable in Kotlin to ensure that Hibernate and the DB and the database creation only happens once before the first test and is shared by all subsequent tests (see note about uniqueness above).  In Java, you could use [LazyRef](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/Paguro/blob/master/src/main/java/org/organicdesign/fp/function/LazyRef.java) or some other thread-safe one-time initialization instead of Kotlin's `by lazy`.

```
private val initialized: Boolean by lazy {
    // TODO: Initialize Logging Here!

    val factory: EntityManagerFactory = try {
        val props = mapOf(
                // Tell Hibernate to use H2, in memory, the myDb database.
                "hibernate.connection.url" to "jdbc:h2:mem:myDb",
                "hibernate.connection.useUnicode" to "true",
                "hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" to "UTF-8",
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "validate",
                // c3p0.max_size is the only option needed to enable c3p0
                "hibernate.c3p0.max_size" to "60",
                "hibernate.c3p0.timeout" to "599",
                "hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" to "false",
                "hibernate.current_session_context_class" to "thread",
                "hibernate.format_sql" to "true",
                "hibernate.max_fetch_depth" to "3",

                // Without the drop, had more schema initialization issues.
                "javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" to "drop-and-create",

                // New for MySQL 8?
                "javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" to "NONE",
                "javax.persistence.validation.mode" to "NONE")

        val tempFactory: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                "my.app.persistence",
                props)

        println("H2 EntityManager Initialized")

        // Returns the tempFactory just created.
        // The try-block evaluates in Kotlin.
        tempFactory

    } catch (ex:Throwable) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        println("ERROR: Initial JPA entityManagerFactory creation failed:\n$ex")
        println("Caused by:\n" + ex.cause)
        throw ex
    }

    entityManagerFactory.set(factory)
    commit()

    // Return true as the value for the `initialized` variable.
    true
}

@JvmStatic
fun testDbInMemory() {
    if (!initialized) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Couldn't initialize Hibernate")
    }
}
```

Then at the top of each Junit (kotlin test) Testing class file that uses the DB I put:

```
@BeforeTest
fun before() {
    TestGlobals.testDbInMemory()
}

@AfterTest
fun after() { HibernateUtil.commit() }
```

The ***BeforeTest*** is to ensure db initialization.  The ***AfterTest*** is to make sure that any uncommitted transactions blow up on (or near) the test they are related to.  It makes debugging much easier.